# Can I deploy a react-app to the SAP Cloud Platform?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-platform, sap-cap

Is it possible to deploy a react-redux application to the cloud foundry environment of the SAP Cloud Platform and is it a supported way of the new SAP Cloud Application Programming Model ?

I cannot find any official resources on that so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do it. You can build a CAP backend app (with a HANA db for example), add an HTML5 frontend app with any framework you like (React, Angular, Vue, etc...) and glue it all together with the App Router, for dispatching your calls.

Here explained step-by-step how to do this:

https://blogs.sap.com/2020/09/01/how-to-build-end-to-end-custom-applications-in-cloud-foundry/?update=updated

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, Yes It should be possible to deploy a react-redux based JavaScript application on SAP CF. You can use the static buildback for on cloud foundry. You can check the documentation [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html).

To answer your second question, I am not completely sure about that, But you can use CAP to generate your database and OData services, and consume them in your application. Additionaly you can check [SAP fundamental react](https://github.com/SAP/fundamental-react)

Comment: Yes I already found that solution as well but thanks. But regarding the second question, I think it should be supported in the CAPM as well because they want to give you the free design choice of which technologies you want to use. There is even a little chapter in the documentation for the SCP which refers to HTML5 applications. I guess this is what they mean when you are not using SAPUI5 but instead choose React, Angular, etc.

Comment: Yes I also week the same. I think this is one of the ideas behind SAP-Fundamentals where they try to separate the Fiori design language from the implementation framework itself.